# $a^x+b^x=c^x$ in geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, big-list

- The Pythagorean theorem.
- Let $A$, $C$, $B$ be three points on a line in this order, and let $D$ be another point, such that $\angle ADC =\angle CDB = 60^\circ$. Let $a=AD$, $b=BD$, $c=CD$. Then, $$a^{-1} + b^{-1} = c^{-1}.$$
- Let $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ be three circles that are tangent to each other and also tangent to a common line, such that $C_3$ lies between $C_1$ and $C_2$. Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be their respective radii. Then, $$a^{-1/2} + b^{-1/2} = c^{-1/2}.$$

See the figure below.

Are there any other results of this type in geometry?

[image]

Comment: *laughs internally*

Comment: where are the points $$A,B,C,D$$?

Comment: $D$ is the vertex of the two 60-degree angles. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the other endpoints of the segments $a$, $b$, $c$, respectively.

Comment: A rather trivial one: if $A,B,C$ lie on a line in this order and $AB=a,BC=b,CA=c$, then $a^1+b^1=c^1$.

Comment: :) I was waiting for someone to say that...

Comment: I honestly would expect some nice relation with $x=1/2,-2$ beyond the ones mentioned, and I will be really surprised to see ones with more "exotic" exponents. Just a gut feeling though.

Comment: See: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

Comment: That's not exactly related. I'm not requiring a,b,c to be integers, and I want a^x+b^x=c^x to be a theorem related to some (geometrical) construction.

Comment: Also we have Pythagorean theorem for reciprocals, but usually we use $h$ instead of $c$ there. :)

Comment: We have some relations with $x=-1$, as mentioned in my previous comment, they have $a$ and $b$ but not $c$ :D. So I don't think they'll fit here. (IMO, it's a surprize to see that there are only three answers in this *big list*.)

Comment: That one is already mentiond by zyx @Flagged

Comment: @Aqua , yes, now I see zyx saying "There must be many more". He/she has condensed all answers to his/her post. :) P.S. : If you are talking about my second comment, I was thinking about some other incidents, including quadrilaterals inside a triangle etc. I'll leave it here as a hint for someone else to find out. ; )

Answer (score 10):

Here's another one. Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid of area $c$ and let $O$ be the intersection point of its diagonals. If $a$ and $b$ are areas of triangles $AOD$ and $BOC$ (or $AOB$ and $COD$) then $$a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}=c^{1/2}.$$

[image]

Comment: The area equation is equivalent to ABCD being a trapezoid.

Answer (score 8):

Exponents $1,2, -1, -2,1/2$, and $-1/2$ are probably the most common, with the complexity of the implied polynomial equation $P(a,b,c)=0$ increasing in that order.  As a random example, the height in the [crossed ladders problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem) satisfies $h^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$.   For the altitude of a right triangle, $h^{-2} = a^{-2} + b^{-2}$. There must be many more.

Exponent $2/3$: the envelope of a line segment of length $L$ with endpoints on the $x$ and $y$ axes is $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = L^{2/3}$.   The curve is called [astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Comment: Nice. Whenever you recall any other examples, put them in.

Comment: The last example generalizes somewhat: the envelope of lines whose x and y intercepts satisfy $a^u + b^u = L^u$ is the curve $x^p+y^p=L^p$ for $p$ Hoelder dual to $-u$.  Another geometrically meaningful case is when $a+b=L$ so that the dual is $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{L}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another one. I don't think it's much popular, but the proof is not too terrible.

[image]

$$\large a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}=c^{2/3}$$

Comment: So what's the proof?